# Android Studio Release Building APK Invalid keystore format Error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

> When attempting to build and sign a release APK I am getting an "Failed to read key androidtckey from store... Invalid keystore format" error on my build. I am using gradle plugin 4.2.1 and Gradle version 6.7.1 on a project running Android API 29.

Here is build gradle release signing config `

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\gradle\\AndroidTC.jks')
            storePassword ='Way2muchstuff'
            keyAlias = 'androidtckey'
            keyPassword ='Way2good4u'
        }
    }
```

Things I have tried:
I used cmd Keytool to make sure the keystore was generated correctly with alias and passwords.
Checked that Gradle was using the correct version of Java.
Android studios is running as admin.
Gradle signign report has the same error: `Error: Failed to read key androidtckey from store "C:\gradle\AndroidTC.jks": Invalid keystore format`

Any help would be much apricated.
Thanks